# pyserial echo itself and response slow under Python 3.3 and Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, serial-port, pyserial, python-3.3

I use pyserial under Python 3.3 on Windows 7 64-bit .
And I want to build a tiny small terminal such as , putty , pietty .

I encounter 3 major problem , 
**(1)When I send the command by serial.write() , then it replies itself to me (ECHO again)
(2)When I wanna print something from serial.read() , it becomes very slow . 
   (I know stdout.flush everytime is the root cause, but i don't wanna anything be cached in the buffer)

(3) i use the miniterm.py under cygwin , and use the windows version Python 3.3 (i used symboling link to acheive it.)**
eg : alias p3='/cygdrive/c/Python33/python.exe' . and "p3 miniterm.py -p COM4 -u 38400" to ran  miniterm , however it seems can not accept my input.
however, under windows native command terminal ,  it works fine, but can not show ANSI color correctly (is there anyway to handle it)

here's my live demo video  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6eZQnFgh2I&feature=youtu.be

and my code

```
def main():
    try:
        global read_thr,write_thr
        beep()
        port_num='COM5'
        baudrate=38400
        init_serial_port(port_num,baudrate)
        read_thr =Thread(target=read_comport)
        read_thr.start()
        write_thr =Thread(target=write_comport)
        write_thr.start()
        flush_thr =Thread(target=read_comport)


def get_key_from_user():
    c = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(),1)
    return c

def write_comport():
    global  ser,    cmd, log_file, isRead
    print("enter Q to quit")
    while True:                
            cmd = input(">>:")

            if cmd=='Q':
                exit_prog()
            else:                
                ser.write(cmd)
                ser.flush()

        pass

def read_comport():
    global ser, cmd, log_file
    cnt =0
    while True:
        element=''
        data=character(ser.read(1))
        sys.stderr.write(data)
        sys.stderr.flush()

        continue
    pass
```